# Replace specific text in INI file

Tags: java, ini

What is the best way to find specific STRING in INI file and replace it with new one.

Let's say that somewhere in my .ini file I have those lines:

```
Something = Something_50054.txt
Something1 = Something1_50054.txt
Something2 = Something2_50054.txt
Something3 = Something3_50054.txt
Something4 = Something4_50054.txt
Something5 = Something5_50054.txt
```

Now I would need to find "Something1_500" in INI and replace it with new string.
(Example: Replace "Something_50054.txt" with "Something_50055.txt")

This is example of code that I currently have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myfileList.length; i++) { //myfileList - list path to ini file
    try {
        if (myfileList[i].trim() != null) {
            File file = new File(myfileList[i].trim());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //Should I do it here?
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

SOLUTION:

```
                Path path = Paths.get(myfileList[i].trim());
                Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
                List<String> replaced = lines.map(line -> line.replaceAll("DBGPS", "TEST123")).collect(Collectors.toList());
                Files.write(path, replaced);
                lines.close();
                System.out.println("Find and Replace done!!!");
```

Comment: Are you new to programming? If you aren't, KMP can help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm (it can be a bit complex if you are new).

Comment: Thank You, I'll check it out.

Comment: You can probably find it already coded in java somewhere, or use a string parser library that has something similar.

Comment: Thank You for your help and your time, I did it, I'll post solution in my original post.

Comment: Very cool solution with java streams, thanks for sharing @Jskako.